# Implementation of 'beads-style' connections in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to Neo4j, but it looks like relationships are only possible between their start and end nodes there without any other nodes in the middle. In other words, I cannot create a relationship 'from A to B via C', only 'A to C, C to B' instead.

Now say we have the following node types (or labels in Neo4j terms): buyer, product, measuring units. How to build the graph if the use case is 'give me measuring units this buyer used when buying that product'?

Naturally the relationships go like this:

`(:buyer)-[:ordered]->(:product)-[:measured]->(:unit)`

But in this model we can't tell which of the units the product was ever measured in (by all buyers) were actually used by the buyer we are interested in. We can only trace buyer to product and then when we trace product to units we 'forget' the buyer and can only get all the units used by every buyer ever ordered that product.

The way I implement that now is that my `:ordered` relationships going from buyer to product carry a property 'unit', so I can do queries like:

`MATCH (b:buyer)-[o:ordered]->(p:product) WHERE b.id = 123 AND p.id = 345 RETURN DISTINCT o.unit`

This, however looks very ugly because logically units should be nodes (and them being nodes comes convenient in other use cases). Here, instead, we have to duplicate them as relationship properties because there is no way to tell 'this relationship starts at the buyer node, goes through product node and without interrupting ends at measuring unit node'.

My question is if there are nicer ways to design a graph for similar queries, and if maybe that level of data duplication is not considered ugly when dealing with graph databases. Or maybe the fact I have such use cases means graph is a wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you encounter the need to cross relationships shows a modelling concern.

I can't remember any e-commerce like applications not having dedicated domain model for orders, would be neo4j or other persistence layers. Orders are an important part of your domain and would then have their dedicated node.

A relationship between the order and the product would represent what is called in common ecommerce apps an order line item which can holds the unit as property.

Comment: In my case there is a traditional SQL database with the orders, buyers etc. The graph is built on top of it to speed up some specific reports that are slow and cumbersome on that source model. So far it's a pilot 'proof of concept' project dealing with aggregated and not individual orders in covered use cases, hence there are no nodes for every order. 

If we have nodes as buyers connected to orders, orders connected to products and orders connected to units, it will work, but what would be the difference from SQL apart from different medium?

Comment: the unit can be a relationship property. the main difference is that you will not have join tables. also a common modelling technique in neo4j is to first write the questions you want to ask to the database and then you model for these questions

Comment: So my solution is acceptabke then, I reckon. Thanks.

Comment: every solution is acceptable, the difference when your model is not optimal or graph oriented is that you will loose the performance capabilities that the db can provide

Comment: What I was not sure about is if using attributes here doesn't scream wrong. I need to think if I really need to keep those unit nodes though.